# Excess Carrier Generation and Recombination

Tags: semiconductors

***Excess Carrier Generation and Recombination :***

The net rate of change in electron concentration is given by:

\$ \frac{dn(t)}{dt}=\$ Thermal generaton rate-Recombination Rate

\$ \frac{dn(t)}{dt}=\alpha _r[n_i^2-n(t)p(t)] \$

How is Thermal generation rate given by \$ \alpha _rn_i^2 \$ and Recombination Rate  given by \$ \alpha _r n(t)p(t) \$ ?

Comment: Personal Note: http://users.encs.concordia.ca/~mojtaba/Chapter%206.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Recombination is a statistical process that depends on the amount of available holes and electrons. Therefore, you can express the *average* recombination rate as a product of the two

$$R = \alpha_r\cdot n\cdot p$$

Generation can have a number of sources (eg. excitation by light - photogenerated carriers), and can be pretty much take any form in the equation - (eg. by modulating the light source).

Because in thermal equilibrium we know that the following equation holds:

$$n\cdot p = n_i^2$$

The equation

$$\frac{dn(t)}{dt}=\alpha_r\left[n_i^2 - n(t)p(t)\right]$$

is therefore simply constructed in such a way that the previous equation is always true for whatever \$\alpha_r\$ you fill in. In other words, for thermal equilibrium:

$$\frac{dn(t)}{dt} = 0 \Leftrightarrow n_i^2 = n(t)\cdot p(t)$$